# How many nonequivalent two-sided $n$-ominoes are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polya-counting-theory

> A two-sided $n$-omino is a $1$-by-$n$ board of $n$ squares with each square ($2n$ in all because of the two sides) colored with one of $p$ given colors (squares on opposite sides may be colored differently). How many nonequivalent two-sided $n$-ominoes are there?

I don't know how to do this exercise because I think that it is not possible for $n$ because when specifying the table for the cyclical index I don't know if a given offset will visit all $n$ elements or not.

Why do I think that it is impossible?

Let say that $n=5$ and we consider rotation by $2$ elements. At the begining, let point first element

$$\underline{1},2,3,4,5 $$

Then we rotate by 2 elements
$$1,2,\underline{3},4,5 $$
And again
$$1,2,3,4,\underline{5} $$
$$1,\underline{2},3,4,5 $$
$$1,2,3,\underline{4},5 $$
$$\underline{1},2,3,4,5 $$

So we have $1$ cycle with size $5$. If I consider just $n$ I don't know which and how many cycles this rotation could create...

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you trying to use Burnside's Lemma?

Comment: What do you mean by *rotation by $2$ elements*? The only symmetries which an $n$-omino ($n > 1$) has are rotating the whole thing by $180^\circ$ around one of three axes.

Comment: Also, you seem to have posted an entire chapter's worth of similar exercises. You'll probably make more progress if you wait for answers to one and then try to apply the same principles to the others.